# Tenses for narrating past and future event

Tags: grammar, tense, grammaticality, sequence-of-tenses

I'm confused with the choice of tenses when it comes to narrating past and future event.

> Do we still have access to the gym after the membership *ends*?

The membership is ending but has not ended. Should it be *ended* or *ends* in the sentence?

> She wants to be a makeup artist when she *grew* up

Talking about a past event, if someone is narrating their career aspiration when they were a kid, should it be *grows* or past tense *grew*? Should it be *wants* or *wanted*?

I remember there is a rule or a specific grammar rule for tenses and time events but I can't recall the term/phrase. If anyone knows, please kindly let me know as I would like to read more about it.

Thanks

Comment: Narration usually means telling the story of a past event, so it uses the *simple past*. Narration does not include the dialogue portion of the story, which remains in whatever tense the speakers use. Both your example sentences are in the *present simple* so they likely won't work as narration. If, for your own stylistic reasons, you are narrating with present simple, normal rules for tense apply. Your first sentence would be good with "ends", but the second should use "grows" rather than "grew".

Comment: If the second example refers to someone's childhood hopes, you should say 'She _wanted_ to be a makeup artist when she grew up'.